# How to submit a form upon selection of an option?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is there a simple way to use a drop down `select` menu as a submit button as well? I'd prefer to not have an `<input type="submit" name="submit">,` just for the form to auto-submit upon selection of an option? Javascript, jquery, php, css and pure HTML answers all work for me.

```
<form name="order" action="" method="get">
    <select type="submit" name="carlist">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Attach a submit event to the form and prevent the default event. Then attach a change event to the select dropdown and sumbit the form there.

Comment: I believe you want to use this as a navigation menu, right? *I knew it* ;-)

Comment: Please reconsider. This is terrible user interface.

Comment: How is this terrible, and what would be a better option? Ebay appears to use an ordered list to accomplish the same thing, but that seemed overly complicated. And, I couldn't find the question on here Daniel, or anywhere else for that matter. I tried several things like setting type to submit before coming here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<select name="carlist" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ofUSEDA/1/edit)

with jQuery you can do like:

```
// in DOM ready function!

$('[name="carlist"]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ofUSEDA/3/edit)

Comment: I'm choosing this one, because it seems simple and efficient. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching an onchange event to your select object

```
<select type="submit" name="carlist" onchange="document.getElementsByName('order')[0].submit()">
```

Then force submit the form with the submit() function.